# Emacs inserting register

Tags: emacs, insert

I am writing a function to insert register "N".
The problem is that when I insert the register, it puts point before the inserted register, while I would like the point to be after whatever register I inserted.

I tried to accomplish this by trying to `set-command-mark` (`C-SPC`) two times, followed by inserting register, and then popping the mark twice (`C-u` `C-SPC` *2). I wanted to do this macro free though, the problem is that I don't know what argument to feed it to help `set-command-mark`. Maybe someone knows how to get it working that way, or has a better idea?

More code if needed to illustrate the case:

```
(defun Navi-insert-register ()
 (interactive)
  (set-mark-command)
  (set-mark-command)
  (insert-register ?N)
 ...
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From insert-register documentation

> Normally puts point before and mark after the inserted text. If
>   optional second arg is non-nil, puts mark before and point after.

Just pass the second parameter as `t` .

```
(defun Navi-insert-register ()
 (interactive)
 (insert-register ?N t)
)
```

Comment: funny to be only 1 character off from the answer! thank you :)